# Como puedo formular esto? (numeros) 1*8*

Tags: java

queria implementar en java pero no sé como la comparacion de dos numeros pero, si un digito esta mal que el otro poner en su lugar "*" de tal modo que 1994 a 1224 seria el resultado 1**4, no se como  hacer esto ya que no puedo descomponer el numero y meter  un * como seria posible con String, pero no lo puedo usar

Ej. si el número secreto es el 3245, debería aparecer inicialmente * * * *, antes de pedir el primer número.

Si el número introducido fuera el 1255 debería mostrar * 2 * 5, y así sucesivamente.

Para compararlo lo tengo que descomponer dividiendo y hallando el modulo

public class practica1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Entorno:
    // Los datos tipo short deberían de ser byte
    short numeroIncognita;
    short contador;
    short numeroComparar;
    short bandera = 0;

    // Algoritmo:
    System.out.println("Es el turno de la primera persona");
    do {
        System.out.println("Escriba un número entre 1 y 100 inclusive");
        numeroIncognita = Leer.datoShort();
    } while (numeroIncognita < 1 | numeroIncognita > 100);
    System.out.println("Es el turno de la segunda persona, usted tiene 10 oportunidades");
    for (contador = 1; contador <= 10; contador++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese un número para  comparar con el número a adivinar, entre 1 y 100 inclusive");
        numeroComparar = Leer.datoShort();

        if (numeroComparar < numeroIncognita) {
            System.out.println("El número ingresado es menor que el número a adivinar");
        } else {
            if (numeroComparar == numeroIncognita) {
                contador = 10;
                bandera = 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("El número ingresado es mayor que el numero a adivinar");
            }
        }

    }

    if (bandera == 1) {
        System.out.println("Usted ha adivinado el numero");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Usted no ha logrado adivinar el número");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega tu código con lo que has intentado hasta el momento y especifica en qué parte estás teniendo problemas, para poder ayudarte a resolverlo de mejor manera.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por que no podes pasar el numero a string?
Pasalo a string:

`int numero = 1234;
String cadena = "";
cadena = String.valueOf(numero);
cadena= Integer.toString(numero);`

Y compara caracter por caracter para ver si hay coincidencias.
Si la hay, dejas el caracter original que representa el numero, si no , lo pisas con '*'.

Comment: No puedo usar String solo me condicionan a tipo de datos primitivos y char

Comment: Proba esto. Dale algun valor al number (ej: 2017) y fijate si te lo desintegra bien.

int number; 
LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
while (number > 0) {
    stack.push( number % 10 );
    number = number / 10;
}

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    print(stack.pop());
}

Comment: no puedo usar tampoco ninguna estructura  estatica ni dinamica, el caso es que no se como mezclar los numeros con el simbolo '*'

Comment: puedes usar un array de char??

Comment: el no puede usar estructuras estaticas ni dinamicas. Array es est.estatica